# UNIQUE constraint failed: post_author.href in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, backend, web-frameworks

I will create a different author table using the user table available in django and I want to combine this custom table I created with the column in the post model. Thus, I will have both the author table and the post table with the posts shared by these authors separately. And also, I will make the user models that I will create in the future with the ready user table. but I am getting the error I mentioned.
When i add authors to admin panel I get this error. When I add 1 author, there is no problem, but when I add 2nd author, I get this error. How can I solve this, what are the alternative ways?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from .utils import get_read_time
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from markdown_deux import markdown
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class GENDER(models.TextChoices):

    Erkek = "Erkek"
    Kadın = "Kadın"
    Diğer = "Diğer"
    NONE = "Belirtmek İstemiyorum"


class Category_Choices(models.TextChoices):
    BİLİNMEYENLER = '13İlinmeyenler'
    KİŞİSEL_GELİŞİM = 'Kişisel Gelişim'
    İLHAM_AL = 'İlham Al'
    YATIRIM_HABERLERİ = 'Yatırım Haberleri'
    GİRİŞİMCİLİK = 'Girişimcilik'
    ENGLİSH_NEWS = 'English News'
    BAŞARI_HİKAYELERİ = "Başarı Hikayeleri"


class Color_Choices(models.TextChoices):
    INDIGO = 'indigo'
    green = 'green'
    yellow = 'yellow'
    RED = 'red'
    blue = 'blue'
    gray = 'gray'
    pink = "pink"



class Author(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    displayName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.TextField(blank=False,choices=GENDER.choices)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="avatar")
    href = models.SlugField(unique=True,editable=False)
    desc = models.TextField()
    jobName = models.CharField(default="Yazar",max_length=30)
    bgImage = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="background")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.displayName

    def get_slug(self):
        href = slugify(self.displayName.replace("ı","i"))
        unique = href
        number = 1

        while Author.objects.filter(slug=unique).exists():
            unique = "{}-{}" .format(href,number)
            number += 1

        return unique




class Categories(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=Category_Choices.choices,default=Category_Choices.BİLİNMEYENLER)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=Color_Choices.choices, default=Color_Choices.RED)
    href = models.SlugField(unique=True,editable=False)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="postpost",null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_category_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.name.replace("ı","i"))
        unique = slug
        number = 1

        while Categories.objects.filter(slug=unique).exists():
            unique = "{}-{}" .format(slug,number)
            number += 1

        return unique
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.href = slugify(self.name)
        super(Categories,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.href

class Post(models.Model):

    authorId = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categoryID = models.ForeignKey(Categories,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)
    href = models.SlugField(unique=True,editable=False)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    readingtime = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)
    published = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    featuredimage = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='post')




    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date', '-updated']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.title.replace("ı","i"))
        unique = slug
        number = 1

        while Post.objects.filter(slug=unique).exists():
            unique = "{}-{}" .format(slug,number)
            number += 1

        return unique
    #@property
    #def comments(self):
    #    instance = self
    #    qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
    #    return qs


    def get_markdown(self):
        content = self.content
        markdown_text = markdown(content)
        return mark_safe(markdown_text)


def pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.href and instance.title:
        instance.href = slugify(instance.title)
    if instance.content:
        html_string = instance.get_markdown()
        read_time_var = get_read_time(html_string)
        instance.read_time = read_time_var






pre_save.connect(pre_save_receiver, sender=Post)
```

and this error

```
IntegrityError at /adminpost/author/add/
UNIQUE constraint failed: post_author.href
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/adminpost/author/add/
Django Version: 3.2.8
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: post_author.href
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you try to make a create with a title that already exists. Thus your href field isn't unique anymore.

Either also make the `title` field unique or you can add some random number identifier to your slug.

```
import uuid

def pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.href and instance.title:
        if not Post.objects.filter(href=slugify(instance.title)).exists():
            instance.href = slugify(instance.title)
        else:
            instance.href = slugify(instance.title) + str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]
```

Comment: Thanks your response but issue still goin...